# The use of in spite followed by a noun and gerund form

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, gerunds

Can I accept as correct an answer like

- "In spite of experts not seeing like it, English is considered an easy language to learn"

Or

- "In spite of English being considered an easy language to learn, some experts... "?

Comment: Hi, I am a Spanish English teacher...

Comment: The first one is not grammatical. [not seeing like it]

Answer (score 1):

I would say both are correct. The second one would be more commonly found.

A little rephrasing would be required though:

> "In spite of experts not seeing **it this way**, English is considered an easy language to learn."

> "In spite of experts not seeing **it like this**, English is considered an easy language to learn."

Similarly, the second sentence could be completed in following ways:

> "In spite of English being considered an easy language to learn, some experts **say otherwise**."

> "In spite of English being considered an easy language to learn, some experts **think otherwise**."

> "In spite of English being considered an easy language to learn, some experts **see it the other way round**."

Comment: The first one is completely ungrammatical.

Comment: @Lambie   Read before you pounce. The answer includes a caveat: "A little rephrasing would be required though:"

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice I was responding to this: "I would say both are correct". regardless of what comes afterwards. Should I have cleared that with someone?

Comment: @Lambie  You might have said "Yes, without rephrasing as you've suggested, the first one is ungrammatical".  Just sayin'